# Antigua Visa Application from Hawaii for Chinese Citizen

Tags: visas, chinese-citizens, hawaii, antigua-and-barbuda

We have a Chinese citizen (national and resident) visiting Hawaii on a tourism visa.

What would be the best way for them to go about applying for a visa to visit Antigua whilst they are in Hawaii? Is this even possible?

I haven't been able to find much information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Visa policy of Antigua and Barbuda - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Antigua_and_Barbuda)

> Permanent residents of the United States and Canada and holders of
> valid visas of the United States, Canada, Schengen Area and the United
> Kingdom do not require a visa.

And to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=AG&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

> Visa Exemptions:
>
> A max. stay of 30 days for holders of a valid visa
> issued by Canada or USA and if paying a USD 100.- Visa Waiver fee on
> arrival.

The Chinese citizen doesn't require to apply for a separate visa (he can use his USA visa) but it is necessary to pay 100 $ Visa Waiver fee when he will arrive to Antigua and Barbuda.